# Why does linalg.solve doesnt use all available threads

Tags: python, numpy, lapack, blas

I would like to know why linalg.solve from numpy isnt using all available threads to do its calculus.

I'm using it to solve for a multidimensional system, in a way that it should solve to find a vector with 27 entries `n.N.N` times. So as it has to do the same type of calculation  many times I though that it would take advantage of all available threads but it isnt what is actually happening. It is only using 16 threads, even if I change `n`, have tested for n = 300 and 400. I also tryed to specify the threads manually from threadpoolctl, it only worked to decrease the number of running threads, but didnt saw difference on the performance though (don't have idea why).

The test code is

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import *
from timeit import default_timer as timer
import math;

import os, psutil
process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())

###### Main time loop ##########################################################

n = 400
N = 300

s = timer()

k_star = np.random.rand(27*n*N*N).reshape((27,n,N,N))
T = np.random.rand(27*27*n*N*N).reshape((27,27,n,N,N))

t1 = timer() - s

print("time to allocate k_star and T = " + str(t1))



for time in range(0,1001):

    s = timer()

    fout = np.transpose(linalg.solve(np.transpose(T),np.transpose(k_star)))

    t = timer() - s

    print("time to calculate fout solving the system = " + str(t))


    print(time)
    
    if time%1000 == 0:
        memory = process.memory_info().rss/1000000000
        print("RAM Memory occupied = " + str(round(memory,2)) + " Gb")
```

May be useful to the answer, the output from `np.__config__.show()` is

```
openblas64__info:
    libraries = ['openblas64_', 'openblas64_']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None), ('BLAS_SYMBOL_SUFFIX', '64_'), ('HAVE_BLAS_ILP64', None)]
    runtime_library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
blas_ilp64_opt_info:
    libraries = ['openblas64_', 'openblas64_']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None), ('BLAS_SYMBOL_SUFFIX', '64_'), ('HAVE_BLAS_ILP64', None)]
    runtime_library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
openblas64__lapack_info:
    libraries = ['openblas64_', 'openblas64_']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None), ('BLAS_SYMBOL_SUFFIX', '64_'), ('HAVE_BLAS_ILP64', None), ('HAVE_LAPACKE', None)]
    runtime_library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
lapack_ilp64_opt_info:
    libraries = ['openblas64_', 'openblas64_']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None), ('BLAS_SYMBOL_SUFFIX', '64_'), ('HAVE_BLAS_ILP64', None), ('HAVE_LAPACKE', None)]
    runtime_library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
Supported SIMD extensions in this NumPy install:
    baseline = SSE,SSE2,SSE3
    found = SSSE3,SSE41,POPCNT,SSE42,AVX,F16C,FMA3,AVX2,AVX512F,AVX512CD,AVX512_SKX,AVX512_CLX
    not found = AVX512_KNL,AVX512_KNM,AVX512_CNL,AVX512_ICL
```

I would appreciate any help to understand what is happening and how I can increase the performance of the running code by using all available threads. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://statistics.berkeley.edu/computing/faqs/linear-algebra-and-parallelized-linear-algebra-using-blas mentions a environ variable `OMP_NUM_THREADS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use 4D/5D matrices with a pretty **small amount of items in the last dimension**. The thing is the current implementation of **Numpy is inefficient in this case**.

Indeed, `linalg.solve` internally calls [`solve`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/8cec82012694571156e8d7696307c848a7603b4e/numpy/linalg/umath_linalg.cpp#L1717) (and the similar `solve1` regarding the use-case) which linearize the ND array so to call [`dgesv`](https://netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d7/d3b/group__double_g_esolve_ga5ee879032a8365897c3ba91e3dc8d512.html) many time in a **sequential loop**. You use the OpenBLAS implementation which is able to compute `dgesv` in parallel with multiple threads. However, `dgesv` is a LAPACK primitive and not really a BLAS one. OpenBLAS is mainly a BLAS implementation though it implement some LAPACK primitives. It is not meant to compute LAPACK primitive very efficiently. In fact only few library can do so (this is actually hard to do). Still, the problem here is that Numpy make a lot of LAPACK calls and **each `dgesv` call only last for a very short time**. Thus OpenBLAS cannot fully benefit from multicore processors since it takes a significant time (ie. at least few microseconds) to share the work with other cores and wait for them to do the work. In fact, **the higher the number of core the higher the parallel overhead**. After all, if you want to organize a party with 100 friends, it generally takes more time to do than with 1 friend, and if the party last for 10 minutes, the organization time will be much bigger than the party time.

With `n = 40` and `N = 30`, here is the scheduling of the OpenBLAS threads on my i5-9600KF cores (only a portion lasting for 0.5 ms so we can see what is happening):

[image: Schedule of OpenBLAS]

Each coloured slice represent the execution of an OpenBLAS thread. Black slices are IDLE time. Most of the time is IDLE and the main thread located on the core 1 do more work than others because **the computational work is not well balanced**.

If you want this computation to be fast in your use-case, this is **better to use only 1 OpenBLAS thread** and **run different `dgesv` calls on multiple threads** rather than trying to parallelize `dgesv` like OpenBLAS do by default. While Numpy could theoretically do that, Numpy is not meant to use multiple thread yet. The only parallel functions are mainly the one of BLAS/LAPACK libraries, not directly Numpy.

Comment: This clarified a lot. Actually I though that numpy would do those `dgesv` calls on multiple threads by default, but actually it doesn't. Do you have a suggestion of library to do those calls on multiple threads? I was thinking on scipy on the begging, but I thought that it would be the same as Numpy. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, I do not think any library do that because `dgesv` is supposed to be parallel so it would be a bad idea to do such a parallelization in a library. This use-case is a corner-case so I do not expect any Python library to support it efficiently. GPU library and more generally, the one computing matrix batches might do that but there is probably no much libraries to do this in Python. In native languages, this is not a problem since `dgesv` can be trivially efficiently parallelized using 1~3 lines, so BLAS developers don't care about this use-case.

Comment: The bad news is that Python is a mess for parallel computing (clearly not designed for that). Fortunately, this use-case is simple enough so you can use Cython or Numba to get a pretty efficient implementation (for Cython, low-level C calls are needed to avoid Numpy overheads). Indeed, both provide a way to do many `dgesv` calls in parallel using multiple thread while not be hindered by GIL.

Comment: I see, actually I use numba for all the rest of the code, but I thought that for those "built in" functions from numpy, it would be more efficiently to do directly from there, but I'll try to write this one with numba then, that helped a lot, thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. Note that the number of thread certainly need to be set to 1 even in Numba. Otherwise, the target BLAS implementation is going to run each call in parallel from multiple threads (which is called nesting and it is very inefficient).

Comment: Okay, but the several calls on the numba implementation with the thread set to 1 won't enforce the code to run sequentially?  I never used numba without letting him to "split" the amount of work (array size) between the threads. I usually define the functions with `prange` on the matrix indexes and let numba to do the work. ( probably not the best way to do in most cases :') )

Comment: If you call yourself the `dgesv` in a loop with `prange` in Numba while using a sequential BLAS calls, the loop will be parallelized and each call will run sequentially in each thread (so in parallel in the end). Just using Numba with not loops like you do in Numpy so far will certainly be better but not much because the main issue is certainly the fact that many BLAS calls are done.